# Would momentarily shorting the supply across single phase AC motor lower its power output long-term?

Tags: power, motor, ac, short-circuit, induction-motor

**Background (optional):**

I found a bandsaw at the side of the road with a broken switch. I jumpered the switch to see if the saw still worked and it worked very well. I took it apart, cleaned it, and replaced the switch. The first time I turned it on, I accidentally miswired the switch and caused a short and the circuit breaker went. I fixed the switch and it works again. However, it has diminished power, not being able to cut the same thickness of wood without stalling.

I thought the new switch might be current-limiting it, but when I jumpered the switch I had similar performance. I thought it might be a mechanical issue to do with overtightening the blade or the wheel, but it doesn't seem like it. Now I suspect shorting the supply may have damaged the motor.

**Question:**

I accidentally shorted the voltage supply with both S1 and S2 closed. The circuit breaker immediately went, but is it possible I damaged the motor, resulting in a lower power output?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbmBzx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Side-question:**

The original switch flipped both S1 and S2 at the same time. I'm assuming this is just for redundancy. My new switch just toggles S1, and S2 is shorted. Could this be a problem?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

Capacitor looks pretty rough...
[image]

Comment: looks like a induction motor, how healthy is the capacitor on it?

Comment: What exactly did you do? What did you short? In general a short at the switch input will not matter for the motor.

Comment: resistance across a cap should be infinite, if it's less then it failed. The cap will be hidden in a bulge on the side.

Comment: "You don't need to be a weatherman to know which way the wind blows." And you don't need to be an electrician to know that that is an ex-capacitor.

Comment: Yes, new capacitor and should be fine : good luck with it - stay safe : mind your fingers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capacitor needs replacing. See if you can find some markings to find out which one you need.

If you disconnect the cap entirely you should be able to run the motor by giving it a manual kickstart.

If it is a start capacitor (that uses a centrifugal switch to disconnect the cap and starter coil) then it will have full power. If it is a run capacitor that remains connected then it will still have reduced power but likely more than you have now.

Comment: Thank you for all your help? The capacitor is a 18uF, 50/60Hz, 250V AC. Are you able to tell from that if it is a start or a run capacitor?

Comment: I don't know where the cutoff for that is, though a better way to tell is to look for the centrifugal switch on the shaft.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has probably been my best experience on the entire stack-exchange network. Just as you said, I disconnected the capacitor and kickstarted the motor and it's operating at full power.

Answer (score 0):

> I accidentally shorted the voltage supply with both S1 and S2 closed. The circuit breaker immediately went, but is it possible I damaged the motor, resulting in a lower power output?

Yes, it's definitely possible. By shorting the supply, you also shorted the motor windings. This could have caused excessive current flow as the magnetic field collapsed more violently than intended. The AC input normally drops the input voltage to zero gradually, you dropped it to zero instantly.

If, for example, part of the winding melted, its resistance could have increased. There are other possible ways excessive current can damage a motor or its capacitor.

Comment: Please see my edit for a look at the capacitor which is obviously in rough shape.

Comment: Yep. Whether that was connected to you shorting it or not, we may never know. But that's definitely not good.